# Kotlin flow transform doesn't emit results when is followed with another operator

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a following Kotlin flow, what I need to do is emit the value from     getUseCase.getResult() and then fire up another flow which depends on the getResults() and emit more values. Code in getContentUseCase.getContent().transform executes and emits the value as expected however value in getUseCase.getResult().transform is never emitted.

However, when I remove the flatMapConcat operator and its content then Im getting values emitted from getUseCase.getResult().transform. Not sure what's what's going on but how can I have working emit in both flows?

```
getUseCase.getResult().transform { response ->
  when (response.networkState) {
    NetworkState.Success -> {
      val contentList = response.contentList
      val result = ResultDomainModel(networkState = NetworkState.Success,
                                                                       contentList = contentList)
      emit(smartSearchContentListResult)
    }
    else -> emit(ResultDomainModel(networkState = contentListResponse.networkState))
  }
}.flatMapConcat { response ->
  val contentList = response.contentList
  val contentItemList = arrayListOf<SmartSearchContentDomainModel>()
  contentList.withIndex().asFlow().map { content ->
    getContentUseCase.getContent().transform { contentResponse ->
      contentItemList[content.index] = contentResponse
      emit(ResultDomainModel(networkState = NetworkState.Success,
                                         contentList = contentList,
                                         contentItems = contentItemList))

    }
```